# UIViewController trouble in landscape mode

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I am trying create app without Story Book and xibs. It must work landscape mode only.
But I got trouble:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/FPzkk.png

Red - it's view of my controller. It's looks like it in wrong position and not rotated.
 For create I use this code in AppDelegate:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    CGRect screenRect = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];

    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:screenRect];

    EmulationViewController* cntr = [EmulationViewController sharedController];
    [self.window addSubview:cntr.view]; 
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];  
    return YES;
}
```

And

```
- (void)loadView
{
    CGRect screenRect = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
    CGRect applicationFrame = [[UIScreen mainScreen] applicationFrame];
    EmuWindow* view = [[EmuWindow alloc]  initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    view.backgroundColor =[UIColor redColor];
    self.view = view;
}
```

It's tested on  simulator with iOS 8. What I do wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You need to make the view controller the root view controller, instead of this:

```
[self.window addSubview:cntr.view];
```

... do this:

```
self.window.rootViewController = cntr;
```

If you don't do this it won't get automatically rotated...

Then if you want it to always be in landscape, you can add this to the view controller code:

```
-(NSUInteger) supportedInterfaceOrientations {
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscapeLeft | UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscapeRight;
}
```